# Fetch is not working

Tags: react-native

I am waiting for successful JSON from server:

> {"...."}

Actual Behavior
I get

> ***SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0***

b is the first letter of word "badlogin". It responds server when sent wrong combination of userName and password. But when I use Postman with the same key values combination on the same address I get correct rosponse from the server.

Steps to Reproduce

```
fetch('http://....', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      userName: "react",
      password: "123",
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson.message);  
    if(responseJson.success === true) {
        alert('successufuly loged');
    }
    else{
        console.log(responseJson.message);  
        alert(responseJson.message);
    }
  })  
}
```

}

Comment: Try removing the trailing `,`after `"123"`.

Comment: Also use your browser`s Web Developer Tools (F12) and examine the Network Tab, check the request to `app-login`, especially the Request and Response part of it.

Comment: @Filburt Didn't help.

Comment: @SaschaM78 On network tab I don't have app-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using FormData to prepare data for sending:

```
......
login = () => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', 'react');
    formData.append('password', '123');

    fetch('http://......', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData
........
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse a string. This is the error. Instead of always parse the json, just add a clausule to check if the request was made with success

```
}).then((response) => {
  if(!response.ok) {
    // handle your error here and return to avoid to parse the string
    return
  }
  return response.json()
})
.then()
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but if I put alert('Wrong connection'); after if(!response.ok) { I get no alert.

Answer (score 1):

Look like the response you got is not `json`

Try to check what is the response you are getting first:

```
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I clearly see the response. It is "badlogin".

Comment: You are welcome and hope you got your problem solve soon.